# stripslashes and mysql_escape_string not removing all slashes

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am having a issue with stripslashes. I cannot get my Javascript code to json_decode because i believe the slashes are intruding.

here is what i have:

```
      $str = stripslashes ($_POST['setImage']); 
  $setImage = mysql_escape_string($str);
  if(json_decode($str) == NULL)
    {
        echo("not valid json!");

    }else{
        $imageUrls = json_decode($setImage);

    }
```

grabbing info from here:

```
<img src="<?php echo $photo['picurl']; ?>" onclick='javascript: setCoverForSet(
                {"photo_id": "<?php echo $photo['photo_id']; ?>", 
                 "original": "<?php echo $photo['piclink']; ?>", 
                 "thumbnail": "<?php echo $photo['picurl']; ?>"});'/>

                <input type="text" value='{"photo_id": <?php echo $photo['photo_id']; ?>, "original": <?php echo $photo['piclink']; ?>, "thumbnail": <?php echo $photo['picurl']; ?>}' name="photos[]" />
```

here is what it is outputting when i print

```
{\"photo_id\": \"2\", \"original\": \"content/employees/1/1363556600bsmiles.jpg\", \"thumbnail\": \"content/employees/thumbs/1/thumb_1363556600bsmiles.jpg\"}
```

the quotes have to be in the input or it will not work right.

thanks for your help.

Updated 7:58 EST 03/22

I am eventually sending it to a table in the database.

here is the whole statement:

```
$str = stripslashes ($_POST['setImage']); 
  $setImage = mysql_escape_string($str);
  if(json_decode($str) == NULL)
    {
        echo("not valid json!");

    }else{
        $imageUrls = json_decode($setImage);

    }

  $photos = mysql_escape_string($_POST[photos]);
  $piclink = print $imageUrls->{'thumbnail'};
  $piclurl = print $imageUrls->{'original'};
  $title = mysql_escape_string($_POST[title]);
  $firstname = mysql_escape_string($_POST[firstname]);
  $lastname = mysql_escape_string($_POST[lastname]);
  $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");


  mysql_query("UPDATE staff SET title = '".$title."', staff_firstname = '".$firstname."', 
                           staff_lastname = '".$lastname."', 
                           piclink = '".$piclink."', 
                           picurl = '".$picurl."', 
                           last_update = '".$todaysdate."' WHERE staff_id = $EID") or die(mysql_error());
```

The only thing that I can think of is that the extra slashes are interfering with the json_decode. 
I only put the echo statement in so that i could see what was being passed after the post.

I did try to stripslashes while doing the mysql_escape_string like this:

```
$setImage = mysql_escape_string(stripslashes ($_POST['setImage']));
```

But gave the same result.

Comment: `stripslashes` undoes the `magic_quotes` damage (rather read up on that!), but you are applying the backslashes back with `mysql_escape_string`, which is doubly silly since you are not sending the string into the database, and it would be the wrong function for that anyway.

Comment: Please explain, where you print what. Please enhance your code with your debug statements. And finally shows what you enter to your form and what gets printed by your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out in case anyone is interested.

I got rid of the mysql_escape_string and that eliminated the slashes. still used the strip slashes though.

I also deleted the print statement from the decode area. Now all is working and it evters the string into the database where it is supposed to be.

Here is the new code:

```
      $setImage = stripslashes ($_POST['setImage']); 

  if(json_decode($setImage) == NULL)
    {
        echo("not valid json!");

    }else{
        $imageUrls = json_decode($setImage);

    }

  $photos = mysql_escape_string($_POST[photos]);
  $piclink = $imageUrls->{'thumbnail'};

  $picurl = $imageUrls->{'original'};

  $title = mysql_escape_string($_POST[title]);
  $firstname = mysql_escape_string($_POST[firstname]);
  $lastname = mysql_escape_string($_POST[lastname]);
  $todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");


  mysql_query("UPDATE staff SET title = '".$title."', staff_firstname = '".$firstname."', 
                           staff_lastname = '".$lastname."', 
                           piclink = '".$piclink."', 
                           picurl = '".$picurl."', 
                           last_update = '".$todaysdate."' WHERE staff_id = $EID") or die(mysql_error());


     echo "<b><font color='#999999'> Staff edit succeeded</font></b><br />";
```

Answer (score -1):

It is more efficient for you to simple use regex and remove all the symbols you do not require,

read on http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I am not sure where this would take place. I stated above that the code has to have the quotes for it to pass the information to a view box and then use it to decode.

Comment: you can use regular expressions to take a string and find, remove or replace a char or a subString with another value, take a look at this website it help you generate the code you require ----> http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=Hello%20look%20at%20/this%20forwd%20slash//%20remove%20them%20&-70